# PHP multiple values in one key of associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, key-value

I stuck with a problem: I have an array with IDs and want to assign theses IDs to a key of a associative array:

```
$newlinkcats = array( 'link_id' => $linkcatarray[0], $linkcatarray[1], $linkcatarray[2]);
```

this works fine, but I don't know how many entries in $linkcatarray. So I would like to loop or similar. But I don't know how.

- no push, cause it is no array
- no implode, cause it is no string
- no =, cause it overrides the value before

Could anyone help?

Thanks
Jim

Comment: You can just add the whole array. `$newlinkcats = array('link_id' => $linkcatarray);`

Comment: What your question is currently asking for seems to be impossible. I think you need to explain it better, provide an *accurate* description of the source data, and better explain what you want the end result to be.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just implode it ?

```
$newlinkcats = array(
    'link_id' => implode(
        ',',
        $linkcatarray
    )
);
```

Or just do this:

```
// Suggested by Tularis
$newlinkcats = array(
    'link_id' => $linkcatarray
);
```

Comment: or alternatively just add the entire array: `$newlinkcats = array('link_id'=>$linkcatarray);`

Answer (score 0):

If your `$linkcatarray` array is only comprised of the values you wish to assign to the `link_id` key, then you can simply point the key at that array:

```
$newlinkcats = array('link_id' => $linkcatarray);
```

If that array contains more values that you don't want included, then take a look at [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to only grab the indexes you need:

```
// Grabs the first 3 values from $linkcatarray
$newlinkcats = array('link_id' => array_slice($linkcatarray, 0, 3));
```

If your desired indexes aren't contiguous, it may be easier to cherry-pick them and use a new array:

```
$newlinkcats = array('link_id' => array(
    $linkcatarray[7],
    $linkcatarray[13],
    $linkcatarray[22],
    // ...
));
```